# E2E - i would like to know how many expectations are allowed in an it block

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

are too many expectations in an it block bad?
only as an example up to a maximum of 7 expectations
or should this be divided into several it blocks?

Comment: It would be good if you could give an example.

Comment: Usually in single it you do an action and verify it. Doesn't matter how many expectations statements you need. Try avoiding verification of multiple actions in a single it block.